# Why is .gitignore deleting files from my projects repository?

Tags: git, gitignore

I placed some files in the .gitignore and now it's deleting files and entire folders from the project's repo.

Anyone knows how and why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: More details needed! This is not a normal behavior. gitignore should have nothing to do with the files deletion. Maybe someone deleted them and you pulled down the changes?

Comment: No, the problem is _ME_ commiting my changes , and it deletes files...

basically i'm using a framework, and the framework files remain unchanged so I added them to .gitignore

The thing is, after I added the Lib and Core folders to .gitignore, I commited two files and the commit deleted the Lib and Core entire folders from the project, and when I pull it _deletes_ from my local repo ...

Comment: If the files don't change as you are saying, you don't need to add them to gitignore (they don't change!). Anyways, if they were tracked and then you added them to gitignore, git will not consider ignoring them until you run `git rm --cached` command, which *only* removes the files from the cache. Maybe you ran the command and forgot to add `--cached` option which results in deleting the file from the cache and the working directory (and adding the deletion action to index!)

Comment: @joker, the thing is, for example, db connections are under those folder, and each user in our team had a different password for the connection, and for both logical and conflicts, that file should never be commited (no one needs to know the db connection, and it's most likely that each user will make it's own configuration ...

So some files like this should not be commited, and all I did was adding them to .gitignore ...

Comment: Yes I understand. Just run the command `git rm --cached <file>` to remove the cached versions. Replace `<file>` with the files names. Then add the paths to gitignore if you hadn't. That's all. Tell me if you have a problem.

Comment: Now I'm using other system, no time to lose with this kind of stuff, I was trying ubuntu 16.04 and it was giving a lot of problems because of php, mysql, apache , etc newer versions, so I just went back to my 14.04 and resolved it by undoing the commit that caused the problems ...

Still, I will try again in a few days because I obviously don't want to stay in 14.04 forever, but I'll tell you something if I need! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else is happening, because files specified in .gitignore are not acted on by Git.

If you did a 'git clean' then files in '.gitignore' are not deleted.  However they are deleted if you enter 'git clean -x'.

Comment: I think this was because it was not ignoring a specific file, and I tried adding the path with and without slash ( path/file and /path/file ), and after that it started doing so ...

I don't know if it was that the problem, when i have some time i'll test it ...

however, I have to check on that git clean, never used it .. gonna search about it

Thanks!